# Polymer 1.0 - Where is the old core list?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

One of the issues I'm having with the new polymer release is identifying which components are replacing the old ones. In the case of the old componente [core-list](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-list.html), I cannot find the equivalent for the new release. Does anyone know which element replace core-list?

Comment: A good source of information for element availability are the element collection repositories: [iron-elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-elements), [paper-elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements), [gold-elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-elements), [neon-elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-elements), and [platinum-elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-elements)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has been replaced with [iron-list](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list).

Answer (score 1):

It's been almost a month since the 2 weeks ETA for iron-list was posted. It may help releasing a "candidate" version if the api is finalized but the team is working on fine tuning the performance.